# My If/Else Statement is Printing at the Wrong Time (updated)

Tags: c, if-statement

When I enter food and a day, my program is supposed to figure out what the correct food to eat. If the user puts in the correct food, my program should say:

> "Mmmm... can't wait to eat [name of food] today!!!"

Instead, my program keeps on saying:

> "Sorry, on [days] I can't eat that..."

after I enter a type of food and day.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)

{
    char day[20];
    char food[20];
    int numFood;

    printf("Enter food: ");
    fgets(food, 20, stdin);

    printf("Enter day: ");
    scanf("%s", day);

    //determines what food the picky eater would eat
    if((strcmp(day, "Sunday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Monday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Tuesday") == 0) && (food[0] != 'm' && food[0] != 'k'))
    {
       printf("Mmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!\n", food);
       printf("Enter the number of %s you can to eat: ", food);
       scanf("%d", &numFood);

       if(numFood > 3)
       {
           printf("That\'s a lot of %s!", food);
           exit(0);
       }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sorry, on Sundays/Mondays/Tuesdays I can\'t eat that...");
        exit(0);
    }
    if((strcmp(day, "Wednesday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Thursday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Friday") == 0) && food[0] != 'j')
       {
           printf("Mmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!", food);
           exit(0);
       } else {
            printf("Sorry, on Wednesday/Thursday/Friday I can\'t eat that...");
            exit(0);
        }


    if(strcmp(day, "Saturday") == 0 && strlen(day) <= 7 && food[0] == 'p')
    {
        printf("\nMmmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!", food);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("\nSorry, on Saturdays I can\'t eat that...");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please say what input I should give and what output you expect

Comment: I addressed the reason of your conditions being slightly off.

Answer (score 2):

Ok now I see your issue

Here you have

```
if ((strcmp(day, "Sunday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Monday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Tuesday") == 0) && (food[0] != 'm' && food[0] != 'k'))
{
    printf("Mmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!\n", food);
    .......

}
else
{
    printf("Sorry, on Sundays/Mondays/Tuesdays I can\'t eat that...");
    exit(0);
}
```

(Omitting stuff from the middle). So either you match the first complex issue or print sorry.

I suspect you want

```
    if ((strcmp(day, "Sunday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Monday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Tuesday") == 0))
    {

      if(food[0] != 'm' && food[0] != 'k')
      {
        printf("Mmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!\n", food);
        printf("Enter the number of %s you can to eat: ", food);
        scanf("%d", &numFood);

        if (numFood > 3)
        {
            printf("That\'s a lot of %s!", food);
            exit(0);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        printf("Sorry, on Sundays/Mondays/Tuesdays I can\'t eat that...");
        exit(0);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Notwithstanding the code not being all that readable but his `if-else` blocks are the root cause of the issue he is having.  While what you adjusted is also off too ;)

Comment: @tijko well that code I posted produces the output he asked for. Please state what is wrong with it

Comment: the code you posted isn't compilable for one.  Just going by the posted code addressing one of the issues of splitting up the 1st condition which I agreed with but having multiple separate `if` conditions for the different days of the week would still cause printing problems which is what op was saying was what he wanted to fix.

Comment: the code isnt intended to compile , its the replacement for a section, if pasted in correctly to the original code, it compiles, runs and produces the desired output

Comment: well you asked whats wrong with it so I don't know how you expect to say its anything.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part I think your code is doing what you expect it to do but there a couple of spots where you have some minor issues with your `if-else` conditional statements.

Aside from adding `\n` characters to keep **stdout** a bit cleaner, I left your code mostly unchanged except for adjusting the conditionals as I have mentioned already.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)

{
    char day[20];
    char food[20];
    int numFood;

    printf("Enter food: ");
    fgets(food, 20, stdin);

    printf("Enter day: ");
    scanf("%s", day);

    // I added a null-terminator for printing sakes.
    size_t food_length = strlen(food);
    food[food_length - 1] = '\0';

    //determines what food the picky eater would eat
    if((strcmp(day, "Sunday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Monday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Tuesday") == 0))
    {

// Here I split-up your condition into 2 separate parts that prevent
// falling into the next block as you had it originally

        if (food[0] != 'm' && food[0] != 'k') {
           printf("Mmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!\n", food);
           printf("Enter the number of %s you can to eat: ", food);
           scanf("%d", &numFood);

           if(numFood > 3)
           {
               printf("That\'s a lot of %s!\n", food);
               exit(0);
           }
        } else {
            printf("Sorry, on Sundays/Mondays/Tuesdays I can\'t eat that...\n");
            exit(0);

        }

/*
 *So now instead of having your `if-else` print out on everyday entered
 *thats *not* matched once you find your day using `strcmp` you enter
 *that block based off the condition.
 */

    } else if ((strcmp(day, "Wednesday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Thursday") == 0 || strcmp(day, "Friday") == 0))
    {
           if (food[0] != 'j') {

           printf("Mmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!\n", food);
           exit(0);
       } else {

/*
 *Here for instance you would always print out this part, on say input
 *of `Sunday` where if there aren't `if-else` checks but using separate
 *`if` blocks like you had the `else` would always be met on days that
 *weren't matched
 */

            printf("Sorry, on Wednesday/Thursday/Friday I can\'t eat that...\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    else if(strcmp(day, "Saturday") == 0)
    { 
        if (food[0] == 'p') {
            printf("Mmmmm...can\'t wait to eat %s today!!!\n", food);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            printf("Sorry, on Saturdays I can\'t eat that...\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see where I added the comments in your code that you needed to set up your conditionals by splitting up the check between food and day of the week.  More importantly was using the `else-if` where before you used separate blocks of `if-else` that will trigger after say a day Monday is found.  Without you exiting this block explicitly now you know the day is Monday so you won't trigger the Wednesday condition but there was a separate `if-else` so your `else` will end up printing everytime like you mentioned.

Comment: @zackBYE344 You are very welcome, I enjoy this...you can always "Upvote" my answer and "Accept" if it was what helped :)